# Generic callbacks for Static Variables in PHP

Tags: php

I need a way to access a static variable for a class using a variable as the classname. Due to how PHP handles static methods and inheritance, I need to access the variable itself and not a static function.

```
class Item
{
   public static $name = 'parent';
}

class SubItem extends item
{
   public static $name = 'child';
}

$classname = 'SubItem';

// This won't work
$value = $classname::$name;

// This obviously won't work either. Not a function.
$value = call_user_func(array($classname, '$name'));
```

The nature of how PHP handles static methods, an attempt to define a static method in the class Item will always return "parent" instead of "child" if called for the class SubItem.

I'm assuming there's a way, but my reading hasn't providing anything of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact, this line :

```
// This won't work
$value = $classname::$name;
```

should not work with PHP 5.2, but **works with PHP 5.3** : if I use `var_dump()` on `$value`, I get the following result

```
string 'child' (length=5)
```

I think your answer is here : PHP 5.3 ; it'll solve :

- The `$classname::$name` problem ([quoting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)) :

> As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to
> reference the class using a variable.
>
> The variable's value can not be a
> keyword (e.g. `self`, `parent` and
> `static`).

- and it should also solve the "*define a static method in the class Item will always return "parent" instead of "child"*" problem, if you use `static` instead of `self` : with PHP 5.3, the static keyword has a new meaning -- see [**Late Static Binding**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Item
{
   public static $name = 'parent';

   public function getName(){
     return static::$name;
   }
}

class SubItem extends Item
{
   public static $name = 'child';
}

$classname = 'SubItem';

$value = call_user_func(array($classname, 'getName'));
```